# Persistent and ephemeral nodes in ZooKeeper

Tags: c++, apache-zookeeper

I want to know how to create persistent nodes in `ZooKeeper`, using `C++` client. I know from [documentation](http://zookeeper.sourcearchive.com/documentation/3.2.2plus-pdfsg3/zookeeper_8h_c4644673723420167d0a89094f4fad06.html#c4644673723420167d0a89094f4fad06), that there is a method `zoo_acreate`. And documentation says about this method that:

> This method will create a node in ZooKeeper. A node can only be created if it does not already exists. The Create Flags affect the creation of nodes. If ZOO_EPHEMERAL flag is set, the node will automatically get removed if the client session goes away. If the ZOO_SEQUENCE flag is set, a unique monotonically increasing sequence number is appended to the path name.

But, unfortunatelly, almost as always with C++ libraries, this library completely lacks reasonable teeny-weeny examples demonstarting the usage of the library methods. As for example in this case where documentation page is about `zoo_acreate` method, but some terribly looking example is totally about something else (it does not even mention `zoo_acreate` method).

So, my question is how to set these flags `ZOO_EPHEMERAL` and `ZOO_SEQUENCE`. It would be great to see this in the context of some tiny examples. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Googling for "zoo_acreate ZOO_EPHEMERAL" gave this as the seventh result:

```
string path = "/nodes/";
string value = "data";
int rc = zoo_acreate(zh, path.c_str(), value.c_str(), value.length(),
    &ZOO_OPEN_ACL_UNSAFE, ZOO_EPHEMERAL | ZOO_SEQUENCE, &czoo_created, &where);
```

Source: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZOOKEEPER-348

Comment: Thank you, sir! I wish ZooKeeper client documentation had such helpful examples.